# Consistent and extendable way to store data for session

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I am making session store which will store some data and read some, This 
session store can store multiple data( SessionInfo) to the map.

Data Structure

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class IBasicStream;

namespace
{
constexpr int kClassVersion = 1;
}

/*
ToSerial and FromSerial are for backward support
*/

struct Calendar
{

  int day;
  int month;
  int year;

  Calendar() : day(0), month(0), year(0)
  {
  }

  Calendar &operator=(const Calendar &other)
  {
    day = other.day;
    month = other.month;
    year = other.year;
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void ToSerial(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    stream << kClassVersion;
    stream << day;
    stream << month;
    stream << year;
  }

  //class version Going to use for future change;
  template <typename streamType>
  void FromSerial(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    int classVersion = 0;
    stream >> classVersion;
    stream >> day;
    stream >> month;
    stream >> year;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  friend IBasicStream<streamType> &operator<<(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream, Calendar &Calendar)
  {
    Calendar.ToSerial(stream);
    return stream;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  friend IBasicStream<streamType> &operator>>(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream, Calendar &Calendar)
  {
    Calendar.FromSerial(stream);
    return stream;
  }
};

struct Timings
{

  Calendar startDate;
  int numberOfDays;
  int duration;

  std::vector<Calendar> customDate;

  Timings() : startDate{}, numberOfDays(0), duration(0)
  {
  }

  Timings &operator=(const Timings &other)
  {
    startDate = other.startDate;
    numberOfDays = other.numberOfDays;
    duration = other.duration ;
    customDate = other.customDate;
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void ToSerial(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    stream << kClassVersion;
    stream << startDate;
    stream << numberOfDays;
    stream << duration;
    int size = int(customDate.size());
    stream << size;
    for (auto item : customDate)
    {
      stream << item;
    }
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void FromSerial(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    int size = -1;
    int classVersion = 0;
    stream >> classVersion;
    stream >> startDate;
    stream >> numberOfDays;
    stream >> duration;

    stream >> size;
    customDate.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      Calendar item;
      stream >> item;
      customDate.push_back(item);
    }
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  friend IBasicStream<streamType> &operator<<(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream, Timings &timings)
  {
    timings.ToSerial(stream);
    return stream;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  friend IBasicStream<streamType> &operator>>(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream, Timings &timings)
  {
    timings.FromSerial(stream);
    return stream;
  }
};

// It should have title
// Reminder Title
// TODO: priority

struct Description
{

  std::string title;
  std::string reminderTitle;

  Description() : title(""), reminderTitle("")
  {
  }

  Description &operator=(const Description &other)
  {
    title = other.title;
    reminderTitle = other.reminderTitle;
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void ToSerial(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    stream << kClassVersion;
    stream << title;
    stream << reminderTitle;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void FromSerial(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    int classVersion = 0;
    stream >> classVersion;
    stream >> title;
    stream >> reminderTitle;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  friend IBasicStream<streamType> &operator<<(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream, Description &description)
  {
    description.ToSerial(stream);
    return stream;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  friend IBasicStream<streamType> &operator>>(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream, Description &description)
  {
    description.FromSerial(stream);
    return stream;
  }
};

enum State
{
  Started,
  Ended,
  Suspended,
  InProgress,
  Invalid,
};

class SessionInfo
{

public:
  //ToDo : Way to make ctor private as only
  //so that Session Class can only access
  //but std::map is currently accessing It so not
  //possible write now.

  SessionInfo() noexcept : mDescription(), mTimings(), mState(State::Started)
  {
  }

  SessionInfo(const SessionInfo &other) : mDescription(other.mDescription),
                                          mTimings(other.mTimings),
                                          mState(other.mState)
  {
  }

  SessionInfo &operator=(const SessionInfo &other)
  {
    mDescription = other.mDescription;
    mTimings = other.mTimings;
    mState = other.mState;
    return *this;
  }

  SessionInfo(SessionInfo &&other) : mDescription(std::move(other.mDescription)),
                                     mTimings(std::move(other.mTimings)),
                                     mState(std::move(other.mState))
  {
  }

  SessionInfo &operator=(SessionInfo &&other)
  {
    mDescription = std::move(other.mDescription);
    mTimings = std::move(other.mTimings);
    mState = std::move(other.mState);
    return *this;
  }

  SessionInfo &SetTitle(const std::string &title)
  {
    mDescription.title = title;
    return *this;
  }

  ~SessionInfo()
  {
  }

  std::string GetTitle() const
  {
    return mDescription.title;
  }

  SessionInfo &SetState(const State &other)
  {
    mState = other;
    return *this;
  }

  State GetState()
  {
    return mState;
  }

  SessionInfo &SetReminderTitle(const std::string &reminderTitle)
  {
    mDescription.reminderTitle = reminderTitle;
    return *this;
  }

  std::string GetReminderTitle() const
  {
    return mDescription.reminderTitle;
  }

  SessionInfo &SetDescription(const Description &other)
  {
    mDescription.reminderTitle = other.reminderTitle;
    mDescription.title = other.title;
    return *this;
  }

  Description &GetDescription()
  {
    return mDescription;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void ToSerial(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    stream << kClassVersion;
    stream << mDescription;
    stream << mTimings;
    int state = mState;
    stream << state;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void FromSerial(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    stream >> kClassVersion;
    stream >> mDescription;
    stream >> mTimings;
    int state = 0;
    stream >> state;
    mState = (State)state;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  friend IBasicStream<streamType> &operator>>(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream, SessionInfo &obj)
  {
    obj.FromSerial(stream);
    return stream;
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  friend IBasicStream<streamType> &operator<<(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream, SessionInfo &obj)
  {
    obj.ToSerial(stream);
    return stream;
  }

  SessionInfo &SetTimings(const Timings &other)
  {
    mTimings = other;
    return *this;
  }

private:
  //template<typename T> friend class ISessionDataBaseFactory;
  //friend class              Session;
  Description mDescription;
  Timings mTimings;
  State mState;
};
```

This is the class which is responsible for storing session information with its interface.

```
template <typename childClass>

class ISessionDataBaseFactory
{
public:
  ISessionDataBaseFactory() noexcept
  {
  }

  template <typename streamType>

  bool LoadSession(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    auto childObj = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    return childObj->LoadSessionImpl(stream);
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void SaveAllSession(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    auto childObj = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    childObj->SaveAllSessionImpl(stream);
  }

  void SetSessionInfo(std::string &sessionId, SessionInfo &info)
  {
    auto childObj = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    childObj->SetSessionInfoImpl(sessionId, info);
  }

  SessionInfo &GetSessionInfo(const std::string &sessionId)
  {
    auto childObj = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    return childObj->GetSessionInfoImpl(sessionId);
  }
  /* will be making SessionInfo as private */
  SessionInfo &BuildSessionInfo()
  {
    auto childObj = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    return childObj->BuildSessionInfoImpl();
  }
};

//

class Session : public ISessionDataBaseFactory<Session>
{

public:
  Session() noexcept : mSessionStore{}, invalidStateObj{}, session{}
  {
    invalidStateObj.SetState(State::Invalid);
    session.SetState(State::Started);
    mSessionStore.clear();
  }

  /*
  The members of the map are internally stored in a tree structure. 
  There is no way to build the tree until you know the keys and values 
  that are to be stored.
  */

  template <typename streamType>
  bool LoadSessionImpl(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {
    int size = -1;
    stream >> size;

    if (stream.IsValid() && size > 0)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        std::string key;
        SessionInfo value;
        stream >> key;
        stream >> value;
        mSessionStore.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
      }

      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  //TODO : in future invalid mState object is going to use more

  SessionInfo &GetSessionInfoImpl(const std::string &sessionId)
  {
    int size = mSessionStore.size();

    if (size > 0 && mSessionStore.find(sessionId) != mSessionStore.end())
    {
      return mSessionStore[sessionId];
    }
    else
    {
      return invalidStateObj;
    }
  }

  template <typename streamType>
  void SaveAllSessionImpl(IBasicStream<streamType> &stream)
  {

    if (mSessionStore.size() > 0)
    {
      int size = int(mSessionStore.size());
      stream << size;
      for (auto &item : mSessionStore)
      {
        stream << item.first;
        stream << item.second;
      }
      stream.Flush();
    }
  }

  //TODO: Add logic to genrate session ID's
  void SetSessionInfoImpl(std::string &sessionId, SessionInfo &info)
  {
    if (mSessionStore.size() > 0 && mSessionStore.find(sessionId) != mSessionStore.end())
    {
      mSessionStore[sessionId] = info;
    }
    else
    {
      mSessionStore.insert(std::make_pair(sessionId, info));
    }
  }

  SessionInfo &BuildSessionInfoImpl()
  {
    return session;
  }

  ~Session() noexcept
  {
  }

  //Timing Methods

private:
  std::map<std::string, SessionInfo> mSessionStore;
  SessionInfo invalidStateObj;
  SessionInfo session;
};

/*

*/
```

These classes responsible for proving stream classes.

```
template <typename childClass>
class IBasicStream
{
public:
  IBasicStream() noexcept
  {
  }

  IBasicStream(const std::string filename) noexcept
  {
  }

  IBasicStream(IBasicStream<childClass> &&other)
  {
    //Nothing needed ...
  }

  ~IBasicStream()
  {
  }

  IBasicStream<childClass> &operator=(IBasicStream<childClass> &&other)
  {
    // Nothing n
  }

  void Open(const std::string &filePath)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->OpenImpl(filePath);
  }

  bool IsValid()
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    return child->IsValidImpl();
  }

  /***Issue here is that 
      i need operator ">>" and "<<" for all
      the implicit types but i don't want 
      for class so can't make genric.
      may be need to create for double and other class Too

      other are using friend function to do that 
    ***/
  void operator<<(int data)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  void operator<<(char data)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  /* void operator<<(std::string & data) {
    auto child = static_cast< childClass * >(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }*/

  void operator<<(float data)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  void operator<<(std::basic_string<char> data)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  void operator>>(std::basic_string<char> data)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  void operator>>(char data)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  /*void operator>>(std::string & data) {
    auto child = static_cast< childClass * >(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }*/

  void operator>>(float data)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  void operator>>(int data)
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  bool IsEmpty()
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    return child->IsEmptyImpl();
  }

  void Clear()
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->ClearImpl();
  }

  void Flush()
  {
    auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
    child->FlushImpl();
  }
};

class BinaryStream : public IBasicStream<BinaryStream>
{
public:
  BinaryStream() : Parent()
  {
  }

  BinaryStream(const std::string filename) noexcept
  {
    mBinaryStream.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
  }

  void OpenImpl(const std::string filename)
  {
    if (!IsValidImpl())
    {
      mBinaryStream.open(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
    }
  }

  BinaryStream(BinaryStream &&other) : Parent(std::move(other))
  {
    *this = std::move(other);
  }

  BinaryStream &operator=(BinaryStream &&other)
  {
    mBinaryStream = std::move(other.mBinaryStream);
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename T>
  void ToSerial(T &data)
  {
    if (mBinaryStream.is_open())
    {
      mBinaryStream << data;
    }
  }

  template <typename T>
  void FromSerial(T &data)
  {
    if (mBinaryStream.is_open())
    {
      mBinaryStream >> data;
    }
  }

  bool IsValidImpl()
  {
    return mBinaryStream.is_open();
  }

  bool IsEmptyImpl()
  {
    return mBinaryStream.peek() == std::fstream::traits_type::eof();
  }

  void ClearImpl()
  {
    if (mBinaryStream.is_open())
    {
      mBinaryStream.clear();
    }
  }

  void FlushImpl()
  {
    if (mBinaryStream.is_open())
    {
      mBinaryStream.flush();
      mBinaryStream.sync();
    }
  }

  friend std::fstream &operator<<(std::fstream &stream, std::string &str)
  {
    int length = 0;
    length = str.size();
    stream << length;
    stream.write(str.c_str(), length);
    return stream;
  }

  friend std::fstream &operator>>(std::fstream &stream, std::string &str)
  {
    int length = 0;
    stream >> length;
    char cstr[length];
    stream.read(cstr, length);
    str = std::string(cstr);
    return stream;
  }

private:
  typedef IBasicStream<BinaryStream> Parent;
  std::fstream mBinaryStream;
};

// Save Session Class
```

Test case :

```
int main() 
{

  std::shared_ptr<IBasicStream<BinaryStream>> mystream(new BinaryStream("ABC"));
  std::cout << "mystream is valid: " << mystream->IsValid() <<std::endl;
  std::shared_ptr<ISessionDataBaseFactory< Session >> sess(new Session());
  auto sessinfo(sess->BuildSessionInfo());
  sessinfo.SetState(State::Invalid);
  sessinfo.SetReminderTitle("This is awful");
  std::string as ="Anb";

  sess->SetSessionInfo(as,sessinfo);
  sess->SaveAllSession(*mystream);
  //bool status = sess->LoadSession(*mystream);
  //TODO Flushing Issue needs to resolve
  std::cout << "mystream is valid: " << mystream->IsValid() << std::endl;
  auto sesinfo_other = sess->GetSessionInfo(as);

  if(sesinfo.GetReminderTitle() == sessinfo_other.GetReminderTitle()) 
  {
    std::cout <<"Both sessions are equal as expected " << std::endl;
  }
  else 
  {
    std::cout <<"TODO Flushing Issue needs to resolve " << std::endl;
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You can improve the question by adding main and some test cases that will demonstrate how the classes are used.

Comment: Sure, Thanks doing it right now :) .

Comment: What is `<io.h>`?

Comment: No use for that now I should be removing

Comment: `#include <memory>` is missing, `std::end` is unknown, at least to my compiler and me. You may also receive a lot improvement suggestions by compiling with warnings enabled ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot man :). Took your advice now i have updated the code by compiling with warnings.It was very useful thanks

Comment: You could fix the dodgy spellings (`Calander`, `straemType`, `ISessionDataBaseFectory`, etc), which would make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally deleted my first review, so this will only cover the main points:

---

- **bug**: I think this is the main reason your code doesn't work. Flushing isn't the issue.

  ```
  void operator<<(int data)
  {
      auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
      child->FromSerial(data);
  }

  void operator>>(int data)
  {
      auto child = static_cast<childClass *>(this);
      child->FromSerial(data);
  }
  ```
- **bug**: `std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc`. This truncates the input file, so we won't be able to read its content.
- **bug**: Conforming C++ compilers do not allow variable length arrays. You will need to use a `std::string` or `std::vector` instead.

  ```
  int length = 0;
  stream >> length;
  char cstr[length];
  ```
- `operator<<` and `operator>>` do *formatted* input and output (i.e. they read and write text), so `BinaryStream` is a very misleading name.
- **bug**: they also don't insert whitespace when writing (so your file will look like: `1Anb11This is awful110000004`. However, they *do* depend on whitespace when reading. So your current input system simply won't work.
- Note that for text input, many reliable XML and JSON libraries already exist.
- `int` does not cover the correct range of values for storing an index into, or the size of, a standard container. Use `std::size_t` instead.

---

C++ uses run-time polymorphism (inheritance and virtual functions) so that classes of different types can implement the same interface, and be referred to through a common base class:

```
class ISession
{
public:

    virtual void Load(Stream& stream) = 0; // abstract fucntion
    virtual void Save(Stream& stream) const = 0;
};

class SessionA : public ISession
{
    virtual void Load(Stream& stream) override
    {
        // ... implementation specific to SessionA
    }
    virtual void Save(Stream& stream) const override
    {
        // ... implementation specific to SessionA
    }
};

class SessionB : public ISession
{
    virtual void Load(Stream& stream) override
    {
        // ... implementation specific to SessionB
    }
    virtual void Save(Stream& stream) const override
    {
        // ... implementation specific to SessionB
    }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ISession>> sessions;
// ...

for (auto const& s : sessions)
    s->Save(stream);
```

However, your current implementation does not allow this, since (e.g.) `ISessionBaseFactory<SessionA>` and `ISessionBaseFactory<SessionB>` are not a common base class, but entirely different types.

If we need only static (compile-time) polymorphism, we can use templates instead, and avoid the common base class entirely.

```
class SessionA
{
    void Load(Stream& stream);
    void Save(Stream& stream) const;
};

class SessionB
{
    void Load(Stream& stream);
    void Save(Stream& stream) const;
};

template<class SessionT>
void DoSomething(SessionT const& session)
{
    Stream stream;
    session.Save(stream); // works with SessionA and SessionB
}
```

It appears, however, that you don't actually need either kind of polymorphism, since there is only one session type.

Comment: 1) I am intentionally using Compile time polymorphism  as it can be faster and we can achieve almost same behavior(no static used).                                                               2) Thanks for pointing out stream bug nd int/size bug i am working on that i will update the code.

Comment: Great. (Also, just to note that when you update the code it's best to create a new question instead of editing the existing one - that way the answers still make sense).